# How to use one REST API for both machines and humans?

Tags: rest, hateoas

I'm interested in building a web service with a REST API. I've been reading about HATEOAS and many of the examples explain the concept by comparing it to what humans do when they surf the web. This has me thinking, why not build the REST API in such a way that it can be easily used by both humans and machines?

For example, I have an internal model of a widget, and this widget has properties like part number, price, etc. When a machine asks for a list of widgets, I can return a JSON representation.

```
{
    widgets: [
        {
            id: 1,
            part_number: "FOO123",
            price: 100,
            url: "/widget/1"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            part_number: "FOO456",
            price: 150,
            url: "/widget/2"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            part_number: "FOO789",
            price: 200,
            url: "/widget/3"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

When a human requests the same list through his/her web browser, it seems like I should be able to take the same internal model and apply a different view to it to generate an HTML response. (Of course, I would decorate the HTML response with other page elements, like a header, footer, etc.)

Is this a sensible design? Why or why not? Are there any popular sites actually doing it?

The biggest drawback that I see is there is no obvious way for a user to delete a resource. In my use case, I'm not going to let users modify or delete resources, so this is not a deal-breaker, but in general how might you handle that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do, but the first premise is simply that the modern "generic" web browser is really crummy REST client.

If most of your interaction is guarded and managed by JavaScript, if you write a "rich client" so to speak where you're relying more on JS generated requests than simply links, forms, and the back button, then it can be a better REST client.

If you're stuck with the generic browser experience of forms and links, you can route around the lack of the other HTTP verbs by overloading POST. You lose some guarantees by intermediaries. DELETE is idempotent, POST is not, this has repercussions, but it's not devastating, and you just have to work around it. You can do idempotent things with POST, but intermediaries won't "know" that they are, so they can't assume its idempotent.

If you end up having to go "POST uber alles" you will either restrict your machine clients to the same api, or you offer up parallel services -- those used by POST stupid clients, and those others that have the full gamut available to them.

That said, if you choose an XML based hypermedia format, then what you can do is add XSL transforms to the XML payloads. The browsers will run the XSL on the payloads creating as pretty a page as you like (headers, footers, enough JS to choke a horse, etc.), while machines will ignore that aspect of it and focus solely on data as given.

Gives you a "best of both worlds" in that respect.

Answer (score 6):

@mehaase

First of all i'd suggest to use one of registered JSON hypermedia formats:

- Collection+JSON: http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/
- Collection.next+JSON:
  http://code.ge/media-types/collection-next-json/
- HAL - Hypertext Application Language:
  http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html

All of them offer explicit semantics for creating links with semantic link relations.

For example with Collection(.next)+JSON you can express your widgets like this:

```
{"collection": {
  "version": 1.0,

  "items": [{
    "href": "/widget/1",

    "data": [{
      "name": "id",
      "value": 1,
      "prompt": "ID"
    }, {
      "name": "part_number",
      "value": "FOO123",
      "prompt": "Part number"
    }, {
      "name": "price",
      "value": 100,
      "prompt": "Price"
    }],

    "links": [{
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://...",
    }, {
      "rel": "edit",
      "href": "http://..."
    }]

  }]
}}
```

This gives you several advantages:

- You do not need to reinvent the wheel for specifying links
- You can freely use all registered link relation types:
  http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xml
- Based on your data structure, you can easily use collection/item semantics of mentioned format
- If need be you can describe input forms as well

As you see from example, it has enough information for transforming to HTML(or other formats).

> The biggest drawback that I see is there is no obvious way for a user
>   to delete a resource. In my use case, I'm not going to let users
>   modify or delete resources, so this is not a deal-breaker, but in
>   general how might you handle that?

for this read "edit" link relation specification, it implies that resource can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can always build a REST API and then build your own, human-friendly web app around it. This is a common practice because you have out-of-the-box functionality and an extendable system for developers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so simply by using HTML with RDFa. So humans can read the HTML and machines can read the RDFa annotations. You need a REST vocab like hydra to annotate the links, and other vocabs, like schema.org to annotate the content.

Another option to use different media types for different type of clients, like HTML for humans and JSON-LD for machines.